# MVC4 Sidebar Active Item?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4, postback

Hello everyone I have a question I am using a template and it has a sidebar menu like that
[image]

the problem is as you see when I click components it is opening however when I click grids in it, it is closing I dont want it to close it should be stay opened. It is working when I start it as html but in mvc it doesn't work. is it about "postback" ? if yes how can I solve it.
thank you very much .

ok this are the codes

```
<div id="container" class="row-fluid">
    <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR -->
    <div id="sidebar" class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR TOGGLER BUTTON -->
        <div class="sidebar-toggler hidden-phone"></div>
        <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR TOGGLER BUTTON -->

        <!-- BEGIN RESPONSIVE QUICK SEARCH FORM -->
        <div class="navbar-inverse">
            <form class="navbar-search visible-phone">
                <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- END RESPONSIVE QUICK SEARCH FORM -->
        <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR MENU -->
        <ul class="sidebar-menu">
            <li class="has-sub active">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="">
                    <span class="icon-box"> <i class="icon-dashboard"></i></span> Dashboard
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li class="active"><a class="" href="@Url.Action("About","Home")">Dashboard 1</a></li>
                    <li><a class="" href="@Url.Action("Contact","Home")">Dashboard 2</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="has-sub">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="">
                    <span class="icon-box"> <i class="icon-book"></i></span> UI Elements
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li><a class="" href="@Url.Action("About","Home")">General</a></li>
                    <li><a class="" href="@Url.Action("About","Home")">Buttons</a></li>
                    <li><a class="" href="@Url.Action("About","Home")">jQuery UI Component</a></li>
                    <li><a class="" href="@Url.Action("About","Home")">Tabs & Accordions</a></li>
                    <li><a class="" href="@Url.Action("About","Home")">Typography</a></li>
                    <li><a class="" href="@Url.Action("About","Home")">Tree View</a></li>
                    <li><a class="" href="@Url.Action("About","Home")">Nestable List</a></li>
                </ul>
```

it is going like that ı need to write jquery or js for this I think but how can I reach the each li class ?

Comment: I add the codes could you please check them

Answer (score 1):

```
var activeurl = window.location.pathname;
    $('a[href="' + activeurl + '"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
    $('a[href="' + activeurl + '"]').parent('li').parent('ul').parent('li').addClass('active');
```

These codes solved my problem.

Comment: but and also I tried this but it didn't work anybody want to tell me why ?

$('#sidebar ul li ul li').click(function () {
            var ids = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#ids').addClass('active');
            $('#ids').parent('ul').parent('li').addClass('has-sub active');
            alert(ids); // Will alert the id if the element has one    
        });